# How can I convert this nginx upstream block to be accepted by the latest version?

Tags: nginx, centos6

I'm trying to upgrade our nginx from `1.2.7` to `1.12.x` but am getting configuration errors on my config:

```
upstream a_trusted {
        server 10.19.81.182:10094;
        check interval=5000 rise=1 fall=3 timeout=1000 type=http;
        check_http_send "GET /a/health_check HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
        check_http_expect_alive http_2xx;
        keepalive 1024;
}
```

The error I get is that `check` is an invalid directive. I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on what `check` was supposed to do, and what it's been replaced with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using this third-party module - https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module which does health checks of upstream servers. You would need to do a build while including this module to have nginx understand and use these directives